# ASIHTTP Request cancelled error in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, image-uploading

I am uploading multiple images data using `ASIHTTP request` method. All Images uploaded successfully but for only last image `ASIHttp` request goes fail. I tried a lot but i can't get anymore.

Can someone help me?

My code is as follow:

```
for(int i=0;i<[arySteps count];i++)
{
     NSMutableArray *StepDetail=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[DatabaseAccess getAddSteps:str]];
     if([[[StepDetail objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"s_image"] length]!=0)
     {
          NSMutableArray *imgary=[[[[StepDetail objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"s_image"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];

                    imagedata1=[[NSData alloc] init];
                    imagedata2=[[NSData alloc] init];
                    imagedata3=[[NSData alloc] init];

                    for (int i=0; i<[imgary count]; i++)
                    {
                        if(i==0)
                        {
                            NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",[imgary objectAtIndex:0]];
                            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
                            NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
                            imagedata1=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];
                            NSLog(@"%@",imagedata1);
                        }
                        else if(i==1)
                        {
                            NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",[imgary objectAtIndex:1]];
                            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
                            NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
                            imagedata2=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];
                            NSLog(@"%@",imagedata2);
                        }
                        else if(i==2)
                        {
                            NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",[imgary objectAtIndex:2]];
                            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
                            NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
                            imagedata3=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];
                            NSLog(@"%@",imagedata3);
                        }
                    }

                    NSString *strurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://inst.niftysol.com/app/webroot/webservices/test.php?said=%d&stepid=%@", appdel.idPARENTID,s_id_live];

                    [self setHttprequest:[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurl]]];
                    //NSString *userid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",appdel.idUID];
                    // [httprequest setPostValue:userid forKey:@"s_user_id"];
                    [httprequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
                    [httprequest setDelegate:self];
                    [httprequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];
                    [httprequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
                    [httprequest setData:imagedata1 withFileName:@"1.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile1"];
                    [httprequest setData:imagedata2 withFileName:@"2.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile2"];
                    [httprequest setData:imagedata3 withFileName:@"3.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"userfile3"];
                    countupload=countupload+1;
                    [httprequest startAsynchronous];

                }
}
```

In above code I've got all images data properly but for last image request goes fail. I get the error:

> Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=4 "The request was cancelled" UserInfo=0x96fbfe0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The request was cancelled}

Comment: I would suggest just remove else if condition .. use if .. if .. if. I faced this problem long back and changing all else if to if solved the issue. It happens with ASIHTTPRequest only I think.

Comment: May be the last file is corrupt, by the way why don't you use Queue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should switch to [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) if possible, very easy to integrate. Though answer your question you should switch to network queue for ASIHTTPRequest.

Declare `ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue;` in header file, declare property `@property (retain) ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue;` and synthesize it as well in implementation file.

```
-(void)doUploadOperation //You can call this method for your upload operation.
{
    [[self networkQueue] cancelAllOperations];
    // Creating a new queue each time we use it means we don't have to worry about clearing delegates or resetting progress tracking
    [self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
    [[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];
    [[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [[self networkQueue] setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<[arySteps count]; i++)
    {
        //First create image data
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",[imgary objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        NSData *imagedata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieURL];

        //Create request and add to network queue
        NSString *strurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://inst.niftysol.com/app/webroot/webservices/test.php?said=%d&stepid=%@", appdel.idPARENTID,s_id_live];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurl]];
        [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
        [request setData:imagedata withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpeg",i+1] andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userfile%d",i+1]];
        request.tag = i;
        [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];
    }
    [[self networkQueue] go];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if ([[self networkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {
        [self setNetworkQueue:nil];
    }
    //... Handle success
    NSLog(@"Individual Request finished");
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if ([[self networkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {
        [self setNetworkQueue:nil];
    }
    NSLog(@"Individual Request failed");
}

- (void)queueFinished:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue
{
    if ([[self networkQueue] requestsCount] == 0) {
        [self setNetworkQueue:nil];
    }
    NSLog(@"Whole Queue finished");
}
```

Hope this helps. Don't hesitate to message if you need more help.